# How to set checkbox to false (Gravity Forms > PHP API > Smartsheet)

Tags: php, gravity-forms-plugin, smartsheet-api

I've inherited some `PHP` code written for a `Gravity Forms` form in `WordPress`.
The `PHP` code uses the `Smartsheet API` to update rows in `Smartsheet`.
The previous code did not recognize `Smartsheet`'s checkboxes.

I've got that working.

However, I have not figured out how to set a checked checkbox false.

There's lots of code, but these (I believe) are the important lines:

```
    $data = array();
//snip    
        foreach($feed['meta'] as $key => $entry_key) {
//snip
            $colid = str_replace("mappedFields_","",$key);
//snip
            $data[$colid] = substr($entry[$entry_key], 0,
                 strpos($entry[$entry_key], "|"));
```

What I have tried to do is force the

*$data[$colid]*

to various values on the PHP side.
I've tried *false*, *"false"*, *0*, even text.

I've tried various fields on the `Gravity Form`'s side, without success.
I've tried intercepting the value in the `PHP` code before it is sent to `Smartsheet`.

If the value is *false* or *0*, then it does not get passed to `Smartsheet`.
If I pass *"false"* or some other value, then the API throws the 1042 error on checkboxes.

Any help is appreciated.

Craig

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what the rest of your code is doing with your request, but sending the value of `false` should uncheck the CHECKBOX cell.

You could also set the `strict` attribute for your cell to `false`. This would allow you to send the string "false" to the CHECKBOX cell, which should uncheck the checkbox in your sheet.

You can read more about the `strict` cell attribute in the [Cell Value Parsing](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#cell-value-parsing) of the [Smartsheet API Documentation](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/)